Swiperjs v11.1.10 unable to find swiper/react module
I am unable to build my react project because of the following error coming from swiperjs v11.1.10.

Cannot find module: 'swiper/react'. Make sure this package is
installed.
You can install this package by running: npm install swiper/react.

The package.json file shows:
"swiper": "^11.1.10"

And the component code has:
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide} from "swiper/react";

However on compile it cannot find the module.  According to v11.1.10 documentation the swiper react module is included.  https://swiperjs.com/react
My code previously worked perfectly fine with swiperjs v6.8.4  when the react module was included as a separate package in package.json.
Thanks for any help.

I had the same issue, and the only solution I found was to add @ts-ignore above the line.

Pretty sure that is just for linting and not compiling.  My issue is the compiler can't find the package when  npm run react-scripts build

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
